# AutoFac LifeTime: Force new instance in specific situation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have the following configuration:

```
builder.Register<EntityContext>().As(
   c=> {
       var entityCtx = new EntityContext();
       //snip snip: some config stuff

       return entityCtx;
   }).As<MyDbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

`EntityContext` obviously inherits from `MyDbContext` which again inherits from `DbContext`.

In my repository's constructor I'm usually using them as

```
...
public MyRepository(MyDbContext context) {...}
```

This ensures to have **one ctx per http request** which is what I want. But now I have the need that for a specific repository I want to have a **different instance** of the EntityContext than is normally being used.

How would you achieve that? The following came to my mind:

- Another config where I use `Register<EntityContext>()....As<DbContext>()...`

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found a proper solution that could work, namely to use the `OwnedInstances` of AutoFac if I understood correctly. For example:

```
class MyRepository
{
    public MyRepository(Owned<MyDbContext> context, MyDbContext context2)
    {
        //context and context2 are two different object instances
    }
}
```

This scenario is especially useful if you'd like MyRepository to run in a different transaction, i.e. it needs to have a different `DbContext` instance than the other repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have different lifetime requirement you must either use another config or manually call container to give you a new instance of the context (or create context instance directly but that is something you don't want to do when using IoC container).

Comment: Thx, you answer somehow pointed me in the right direction. I just found a solution on how to implement this with AutoFac